# Expect script fails resolve hostname host

Tags: expect

I am trying to run the below expect scriipt to login to the multiple hosts and run the some commands on those hosts.
I have two files 1) host.txt which contains host names another 2) commands.txt which contains commans to execute.
Though, while i am running it its through an error which i have given below.. Please advise .. I went through all the solutions over the stackoverflow but did not get things working ..

SCRIPT CODE .....

```
$ cat myexpc
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Set up various other variables here ($user, $password)
set timeout 20
set user karn
set password 123
# Get the list of hosts, one per line #####
set f [open "host.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Get the commands to run, one per line
set f [open "commands.txt"]
set commands [split [ read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hosts {
    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect "password:"
    send "$password\r"

    # Iterate over the commands
    foreach cmd $commands {
        expect "% "
        send "$cmd\r"
    }

    # Tidy up
    expect "% "
    send "continue\r"
    expect eof
    close
}
```

====================

```
    SCRIPT RUN & FAILURE CODE ..........
    $ ./myexpc
    spawn ssh karn@Server1
The authenticity of host 'server1 (192.2.47.194)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 33:r3:31:dd:a1:8a:38:08:b7:b1:e1:24:bc:cd:e2:5c.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
123
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
/bin/grep  192.17.14.1 /etc/ldap.conf /etc/resolv.conf
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes

y
y
y
y
y
y
```

it keeps on running

Comment: Are you able to connect to your host manually without this script? If yes then may be you should try adding timeout in your expect code.

Comment: @Ashish yes manually i can reach to the hosts define in "host.txt". though timemout value has been set to 20 already.

Comment: hey i think you are missing $ before host, it should be "spawn ssh $user@$host"

Comment: while i am adding $host its giving whole bunch of errors

Comment: can you share the error you get

Comment: @Ashish   i just update the error on the actual question , please see

Comment: "expect -d myexpc" might give some more insights